# Linksys VOIP System Layout

Tags: voip

I am completely new to VOIP systems and I want to learn how to setup a small business VOIP system. I understand that for a small business, there is 1 physical phone line that comes in with phone and adsl traffic on it. I am looking at the Linksys SPA9000 to use for the VOIP service, but can someone please explain how a network diagram goes together exactly? Ie:

------> Phoneline/Internet ------> Modem/Router ------> Switch ------> SPA9000

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram that you showed would be how it should be connected.